# How do I hide or suppress authentication popups in a webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have made an authenticated search webview which takes the authentication through username and password at login. Every time I am on the webview through search, it pops up the authentication message for user already logged in (errorcode 410 I believe). How do I suppress or hide the same?

Should I use the following code?

```
public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl ) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Authentication Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (errorCode == 410) {
        //webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host, realm, username, password);
        // Show alert to enter username and password.
        // Then, when those are entered in the alert,
        // set it through the setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(...)
        // shown below and then reload the site.
    }
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}
```

If so, how do I go about suppressing or hiding the popup with code?

Comment: Well, I definitely wouldn't use HTTP 410 (see the [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)). You're probably thinking of 401. As far as suppressing the popup goes though, you'll have to find out/give more information about how it gets displayed or what the code for it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following implemented [`onReceivedHttpAuthRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to your WebViewClient class:

```
....

    public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl ) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest( WebView view, final HttpAuthHandler handler, final String host, final String realm) {
            // Replace SAVED_USERNAME and SAVED_PASSWORD with your authentication details.
            handler.proceed(SAVED_USERNAME,SAVED_PASSWORD);
    }

}
```

See *[documentation page for onReceivedHttpAuthRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)*.

Comment: I have that in my code already, still shows authentication popups : @Override
     public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest( WebView view, final HttpAuthHandler handler, final String host, final String realm ){
       
      
       handler.proceed(USERNAME,PASSWORD);


    }